# Android app for monitoring sendBroadcast() messages

Tags: android, debugging, testing, broadcast

I'm adding sendBroadcast() to one of my apps but I won't be consuming the broadcast myself, so I'm wondering if there is a utility app or a debugger component I can use to monitor all sendBroadcast() messages on my device and see if the message I'm broadcasting is getting across.

I know I could probably throw something together, but if there is an exist app (that is known to work ;) that is the preferred route.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write this as an ordinary SDK app. You cannot listen for arbitrary broadcasts, only specific ones you explicitly register for.

Some broadcast information may be written to LogCat (I forget, haven't looked for that in ages).

Answer (score 0):

Go figure, searched for 30 minutes for this and then found it 10 minutes after typing up a SO question...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger